# Netsuite AP aging throug SuiteAnalytics connect

Tags: odbc, netsuite

Hope you have a great day and help me with the problem

I am trying to recreate AP aging through ODBC. Everything is working fine except the Journal transactions.
In Netsuite Saved searches there is a field remainingamount which is not available in connection schema for some reason. We have tried to conctact Netsuite directly but still got no any feedback from them.
There is a field *foreignamountunpaid/foreignamountunused* in transactionline table I am trying to use right now. And with bills and Expense reports it's working totaly fine.

However, for no reason we have some problems with **some** of JEs. In some of them there is null value when in the Saved search there is a value for that line.
I tried to analyse why this is happening but it's look totaly random.

So, do you by any chance know if there is a better field for amount remaining I could use throug ODBC connection? Or why some of JEs have null values in those fields *foreignamountunpaid/foreignamountunused* ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm new to NetSuite world and I am also experiencing it on some invoices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the way to make it work

```
nvl(nvl(transactionline.foreignamountunpaid, -transactionline.foreignpaymentamountunused),-transactionline.foreignamount)
```

this column in sql gives you desired result